# Same test dataset generates different accuracies upon evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

When the **same** test dataset is fed into the trained model to perform evaluation.
Different accuracies are returned each time. What would be the reason?
Any solution to fix it?

```
directory is shown as below ,each class has 200-300 images
dataset
  |_ class1
  |_ class2
  |_ class3
   ......
```

The code is shown as below

```
#import dataset
dataset_path = '<directory>'
DIR = pathlib.Path(dataset_path)

#validation set
validation_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DIR,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(150, 150),
  batch_size=32)
  
#test set
val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_set)
test_set = validation_set.take(val_batches // 5)
validation_set = validation_set.skip(val_batches // 5)

#build model and train model
#......
#At the end of the training
#accuracy:0.9047  val_accuracy:0.8942

#evaluate model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_set)
#I run this line of code several times and each time it returns different accuracy 
#Says, the accuracies may range from 0.902 to 0.934
```

Comment: Although it will not completely guarantee a deterministic output you could set the seed value `tf.random.set_seed(0)`.

Comment: @yudhiesh Ok. I'll try it and inform you whether or not it works. Thanks.

Comment: @yudhiesh Sadly it still doesn't work as expected. But I appreciate your advice anyhow.

Comment: How different are the results?

Comment: @yudhiesh Same. The lowest can be something around 0.90. The highest can go up to 0.96. I really have no clue why it happens. Everything seems to work fine, other than this part......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, I managed to reproduce your results. The problem arises *only* when you use a GPU because some GPU operations are not deterministic. Try to set:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

Or alternatively, if you use google colab, Runtime>Change Runtime Type>Hardware accelerator>None

Comment: I see...But without GPU, it's gonna take forever to complete the training haha. Thanks for giving me some clues. I'll work on that in a while

Comment: Update: I tried to handle the non-determinism of GPU but then the problem wasn't fixed. Then I came up with another solution which is to move the test dataset to separate files instead of using the `.take()` and `.skip()` methods. Anyway I appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 1):

Where is your model defined? If you define the model with random initialization (i.e., you don't specify initialization) and the model is created every time you launch the script, it's normal that you get different accuracy.

Initialization plays a role: if you start with 2 differently initialized models, after training you will usually get two similar but still different models

Comment: I've corrected the mistake. Thanks for the reminder. And I believe it's nothing much to do with random initialization things. Because the model is **trained**, the problem is that the  `model.evaluate(test_set)` generates different figures every time I run this particular cell even with the same test dataset. I don't understand why

Comment: Initialization plays a role: if you start with 2 different initialized models, you will usually get two similar but still different trained models. That's what actually happening in your code: you get models that have each time similar, but not equal, accuracy

Comment: (+1 for the answer). @Sunnday: if you specify a specific random seed when you train the model, then the trained model will be the same every time and the perf on the test set will also be the same. you could also try to save the model to a file after training, and re-use always the same model file when you test.

Comment: You're right, I managed to reproduce your results. The problem arises only when you use a GPU because some GPU operations are not deterministic. Try to set:

import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

Or alternatively, if you use google colab, Runctime>Change Runtime Type>Hardware accelerator>None